# See pip installations in a PyCharm Project?

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a possibility to see all pip installed packages in Pycharm?
Because I have the Problem: I write in PyCharm and it works fine, but now I want to move the project to a server... And now I don't know how can I quickly export this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type in terminal

```
pip list
```

this will show all the installed requirements in the terminal.

try the following line to update all installed requirements into the requirements.txt file

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

then in the server after making a virtualenv run the following command to install all the requirements

```
pip install -r requiremnets.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

There is such tool provided by PyCharm. You can find it in `Tools -> Sync Python Requirements...`

[image]

Edit:

If after you're receiving an empty file, PyCharm would also suggests you to install certain plugins.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `pip freeze >requirements.txt` locally to import the environment you need into the file,

then  use the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`  on the server to install the required environment